# How to set themes dynamically?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-theme, color-picker

I want to add themes to my application. For this I added color picker dialog.

When the user will select the color from color picker theme of the application should change, I want to change the color of navigation bar and floating button.

How can I set themes dynamically?

Thank you..

EDIT :

Settings Activity.

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        final ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog();
        colorPickerDialog.initialize(R.string.dialog_title, new int[]{Color.CYAN, Color.LTGRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.YELLOW}, Color.YELLOW, 3, 2);
        colorPickerDialog.setOnColorSelectedListener(new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onColorSelected(int color) {


                Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "selectedColor : " + color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        LinearLayout theme = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.theme);

        theme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                colorPickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "colorpicker");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `setTheme()` in your activity and  recreate the activity

OR
you can use `setTheme()` in your activity and set the colors manually (toolbar background, fab color, statusbar color) if you know exactly, which colors you want to change.

Note that `setTheme()` sets the theme dynamically, but it won't redraw your activity. So everything being redrawn after `setTheme()` already uses your new theme! (can be seen in Lollipop's/Marchmallow's recents apps list -> the color at the top of your app will already change after `setTheme()` even without recreating the activity).

It seems like there's no way to dynamically create a theme. So I'd recommend only offering a choice pre-defined themes (in XML) and applying these. A workaround for fully dynamic color changing would be to change the colors on all elements yourself. I wrote me a method to do this for toolbar and actionbar. So heres the method, based on the `enum Colors {RED, GREEN, BLUE}`:

```
private void setColors(COLORS color) {
    int toolbarColor = 0;
    int statusbarColor = 0;
    switch (color) {
        case GREEN:
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Green);
            toolbarColor = R.color.green;
            statusbarColor = R.color.greenDark;
            break;
        case RED:
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Red);
            toolbarColor = R.color.red;
            statusbarColor = R.color.redDark;
            break;
        case BLUE:
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar_Blue);
            toolbarColor = R.color.blue;
            statusbarColor = R.color.blueDark;
            break;
    }
    mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, toolbarColor));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, statusbarColor));
    }
}
```

where AppTheme.NoActionBar.Green, AppTheme.NoActionBar.Red and AppTheme.NoActionBar.Blue extend AppTheme.NoActionBar and only overwrite the primary color, primary dark color and accent color.

Comment: Please check the edited question. That's my settings activity. Can you please guide through code in that? Thank you. @Valentin Kuhn

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have any time yesterday.
I looked it up again and it really seems like there's no way to dynamically create a theme. I'd recommend only giving a choice of different predefined themes (which are defined in XML) and applying these. A workaround would be to manually set the colors, but that wouldn't really change the primary/accent color...
I wrote me a method to apply different themes based on an ENUM (here: RED, GREEN, BLUE), see next comment

Comment: couldn't put it in the comments, edited my answer instead

Answer (score -1):

You can't set theme dynamically. You can, however, set a theme **before** you call `setContentView`, so I suggest you store your theme in `SharedPreferences`, and when user selects new theme, restart activity and apply your new theme.

Comment: Can you guide me an example for this?

Comment: Activity has method setTheme. Create several theme resources in styles.xml and supply different themes to the method.